# DPLYR: Convert multiple columns from character to integer

Tags: r, dplyr, type-conversion, integer, character

I am working with a long table, but need to convert (part of) it to a wide table to use the data in the staistical package Vegan. However, when I use the pivot-wider function, all columns end up as characters. I can't find the solution how to convert the colums (with scientific species names as headers) into integers. I've read many posts but all solutions so far won't work. The code I used to create the table:

```
biota_C <- (biota_species) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(Species, Station, Numbers) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Station, values_from = Numbers) %>%
  t() %>%
  row_to_names(row_number = 1)
```

The resulting table looks fine to me except for the datatypes.[Species table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owEBg.jpg)

```
> glimpse(biota_C)
 chr [1:306, 1:27] "0" "1" "0" " 0" " 1" " 2" "1" "2" "0" "4" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "3" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" " 0" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:306] "X00A2" "X00A4" "X00A6" "X00B2" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:27] "Aphelochaeta marioni" "Arenicola marine" "Aricidea minuta" "Bathyporeia saris" ...
```

Obviously I am overlooking something.

Best, Berry

Answer (score 1):

You transposed the whole data.frame with the row.names, hence everything is converted to character.

try something like this:

```
df = data.frame(Species = rep(c("Aphelochaeta marioni","Arenicola marine","Aricidea minuta","Bathyporeia saris"),each=5),
Station=rep(letters[1:5],4),Numbers=rpois(20,20))

df %>% 
pivot_wider(names_from = Station, values_from = Numbers) %>%
column_to_rownames("Species") %>% 
t() %>% glimpse()

 int [1:5, 1:4] 15 19 19 22 27 25 20 21 17 23 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "Aphelochaeta marioni" "Arenicola marine" "Aricidea minuta" "Bathyporeia saris"
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the picture of the table, you can see some additional whitespace in the species table, so the columns in this table are characters. You can use `mutate_all` from `dplyr` together with `as.numeric` to convert the type:

```
biota_C <- biota_C %>% 
  mutate_all(as.numeric)
```

Comment: Thanks. This gives more or less the same error: Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'character')"

Answer (score 1):

We can use `across` with `mutate` in `dplyr` 1.0.0

```
library(dplyr)
biota_C <- biota_C  %>%
              mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but I get an error: Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'character')"

Comment: @BerryvanderHoorn  If you have a `matrix` object, then convert to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame` i.e. `as.data.frame(biota_C) %>% mutate(..`

Comment: That works akrun, many thanks! Apparently transposing the data converts it to a matrix. I'll take that into account.